# How to implement many to many relationship in oracle database correct?

Tags: database, oracle

I have a question about implementing simple relationship between four tables.

```
employee
department
course
course_employee
```

Created them all but I just want to be sure I am not missing something that can harm the db design. Here are the relations:

```
employee to department -> many to one
employee to course -> many to many
```

the course_employee table is mediator between course and employee tables.

Here is my SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
  id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  username VARCHAR2(20),
  password VARCHAR2(100),
  email VARCHAR2(40),
  department_id NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE department(
  id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  department_name VARCHAR2(40),
  location VARCHAR2(30)
);


ALTER TABLE employee
ADD CONSTRAINT department_id
  FOREIGN KEY (department_id)
  REFERENCES department(id);

CREATE TABLE course(
  id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  course_code  VARCHAR2(20),
  course_name VARCHAR2(100),
  difficulty VARCHAR(10),
  duration NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE course_employee (
  course_id NUMBER,
  employee_id NUMBER
);

ALTER TABLE course_employee
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_course FOREIGN KEY(course_id)
REFERENCES course(id);


ALTER TABLE course_employee
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_employee FOREIGN KEY(employee_id)
REFERENCES employee(id);
```

And the exported ER diagram from sql developer:

[image]

I would like to add also completed courses for employee but I am not sure if this is achieved by some relationship. Can somebody who is aware of DB design share opinion? Thank you very much!

Comment: Your create table statements look ok to me - with regards to your extra requirement to add completed courses - that could be included in the course_employee table, perhaps as a column such as "course_status"

Comment: many thanks for the quick reply :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can track the status of a training an employee enrolled for in the course_employee table. This table can hold any data specific to the fact that an employee enrolled into a course.

Comment: Do you mean adding a column completed BOOLEAN  in the mediator table course_employee will do the trick?

Comment: My only concern on this design is if an employee could retake the same Course and you wanted to keep track of something like beginDate, endDate, Grade...

Comment: @Vercelli: this is greatly simplified version of a course booking solution. There are no slots associated with the courses. In reality, you would not associate a course directly with a participant, you would associate a slot of the course with the participants. If you retake a course, then you will attend a different slot of the course. But tracking whether a participant completed a course should be stored in the table associating the participant with the slot.

Comment: How would you handle something like a "primary" column.  For instance, an employee has 5 courses, but only 1 could be marked as "primary".  Would that boolean (NUMBER 0,1) type field be added to course_employee above?

Answer (score 1):

Your course_employee table is the junction table (many side) between the course table and the employee table. The course_id and employee_id must be both the foreign key and the primary key for the course_employee table in order for it to be a many-to-many relationship.